# (Vis.js network) How do I put the nodes array in a loop to get my data?

Tags: for-loop, vis.js, vis.js-network

I have several `div` containing data that I want to use as *id*, *label*, *title* etc for the nodes of my network.

I made a `for` loop which gets all the existing `div` with a specific class, and then stores the contents of all the child `div` in variables.
In order to generate as many nodes as there are `div`, I assume the next step is to put the nodes array inside the loop, but if I do that the network doesn't load.

Here's the code that I have right now: it generates only one node, containing the data of the last `div`, since the nodes array is out of the loop. How do I correctly put it in the loop?

```
    var nombreNodes= $('.personnage');
    for (var i = 0; i < nombreNodes.length; i++) {
        var nodesId = document.getElementsByClassName('id')[i].innerHTML;
        var nodesLabel = document.getElementsByClassName('label')[i].innerHTML;
        var nodesTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('title')[i].innerHTML;
        var nodesGroup = document.getElementsByClassName('group')[i].innerHTML;
        var nodesFontSize = document.getElementsByClassName('fontSize')[i].innerHTML;
        var nodesFontColor = document.getElementsByClassName('fontColor')[i].innerHTML;
        var nodesFontFace = document.getElementsByClassName('fontFace')[i].innerHTML;
    }

    // create an array with nodes
    var nodes = [
        {id: nodesId, 
        label: nodesLabel, 
        title: nodesTitle, 
        group: nodesGroup, 
        font: nodesFontSize + ' ' + nodesFontFace + ' ' + nodesFontColor},
    ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I think, you need to add the nodes to an array, which will be available from outside of the for-loop. The following example should work (currently untested)

```
var nodes = [];
var nombreNodes= $('.personnage');
for (var i = 0; i < nombreNodes.length; i++) {
    var nodesId = document.getElementsByClassName('id')[i].innerHTML;
    var nodesLabel = document.getElementsByClassName('label')[i].innerHTML;
    var nodesTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('title')[i].innerHTML;
    var nodesGroup = document.getElementsByClassName('group')[i].innerHTML;
    var nodesFontSize = document.getElementsByClassName('fontSize')[i].innerHTML;
    var nodesFontColor = document.getElementsByClassName('fontColor')[i].innerHTML;
    var nodesFontFace = document.getElementsByClassName('fontFace')[i].innerHTML;

    nodes.push({
        id: nodesId, 
        label: nodesLabel, 
        title: nodesTitle, 
        group: nodesGroup, 
        font: nodesFontSize + ' ' + nodesFontFace + ' ' + nodesFontColor
    });
}
// This dataset can be added to the vis.network
var dataSet = new vis.DataSet(nodes);
```